# What do you call this notation within a WP template? <!-- wp:template-part {} /-->

Tags: wordpress

I have since a very long time again a Wordpress blog set up and to test I use the theme "`Twenty Twenty-Three v 1.2`. To my dismay I found in the folder of the theme no functions.php file and within the HTML files is worked with wp tags that are commented out. Especially the commenting out I find very strange and do not understand how it works. Therefore I would like to know what is called this kind of templating on wordpress to read up on it.

**Example home.html**

```html
<!-- wp:template-part {"slug":"header","tagName":"header"} /-->

<!-- wp:group {"tagName":"main","style":{"spacing":{"margin":{"top":"var:preset|spacing|50","bottom":"var:preset|spacing|70"}}},"layout":{"type":"constrained"}} -->
<main class="wp-block-group" style="margin-top:var(--wp--preset--spacing--50);margin-bottom:var(--wp--preset--spacing--70)">
    <!-- wp:heading {"level":1,"align":"wide","style":{"spacing":{"margin":{"bottom":"var:preset|spacing|60"}}}} -->
    <h1 class="alignwide" style="margin-bottom:var(--wp--preset--spacing--60)">Mindblown: a blog about philosophy.</h1>
    <!-- /wp:heading -->

// and so on ...
```

Comment: What you're seeing is a [block-based theme](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/block-themes/). It's something that the WordPress team introduced recently, and a new way to build themes that doesn't use PHP that much. The `wp:template-part` bit you're referring to is the HTML counterpart of the [get_template_part()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) PHP function. Have a look at the official documentation to learn more if you haven't already.